# merge values together in a 2d array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

having a little bit of an issue trying to merge values in a 2d array.

For example:

```
const formatBids = 
 [
   [4444, 10000],
   [4444, 500],
   [4455, 500],
 ];
```

I want to sum up the 2nd param of the array if the first param are the same, so the end result being:

```
 [
   [4444, 10500],
   [4455, 500],
 ];
```

i have tried the following but its continually adding to itself producing the wrong results:

```
formatBids.map(bid => {
  const map = new Map([bid]);
  formatBids.forEach(arr => (arr[1] += map.get(arr[0]) ?? 0));
});
```

unsure the best way to tackle this. Ideas?

Comment: `formatBids.map()` will always return an array with 3 items if `formatBids` contains 3 items.

Comment: Try not to mutate your input data but instead create a *new* result array

Comment: I think you should use an Object instead of a 2d Array to store data. From post, i think the 0th element of the nested array is unique. So maybe something like this might help https://jsfiddle.net/xgfdhw5r/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use an Object as a sort of map and use the first item in an array as the key. Then you can convert it back to an Array using Object.entries(). Like so:

```js
const formatBids = 
 [
   [4444, 10000],
   [4444, 500],
   [4455, 500],
 ];
 
const totals = {}

for (const bid of formatBids) {
  totals[bid[0]] = (totals[bid[0]] || 0) + bid[1];
}

console.log("as object:", totals, "as array:", Object.entries(totals));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const formatBids = [
  [4444, 10000],
  [4444, 500],
  [4455, 500],
];

let merged = {}

formatBids.forEach((ele) => {
  let key = parseInt(ele[0]);
   merged[key] = (merged[key] ?? 0)+ele[1];
})

let mergedArr = Object.entries(merged);
console.log(mergedArr)
```

This is the another way of doing this

1. Sort the array based on first index
2. Push into array if currentArr(merged Array) is empty.
3. If not empty, then check the first element at last index of currentArr is equal to the first index of CurrentElement.

   - if yes, then add the 2nd element value to the currentArr's[n-1][1]
   - else, insert currentElement into the currentArr

```js
const formatBids = [
  [4444, 10000],
  [4444, 500],
  [4455, 500],
];
var mergedArr = formatBids.sort().reduce((currentArr, currentElement) => {
  let n = currentArr.length;
  if (n === 0) return [currentElement];

  if (currentElement[0] === currentArr[n - 1][0]) {
    currentArr[n - 1][1] += currentElement[1];
    return currentArr;
  } else return [...currentArr, currentElement];
}, []);
console.log(mergedArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const formatBids = 
 [
   [4444, 10000],
   [4444, 500],
   [4455, 500],
 ];
 
const result = Object.entries(formatBids.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
   if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = value;
   else acc[key] += value;
   return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```